# What if property is declared as private? How to call it in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties

My question is simple: if a property is declared as private - how to call it?

In java we use getter&setter in which variable is private but in C# property is public; if I make it private, then in main class, it can't be called.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace staticProperty
{
    class Class1
    {
        private string name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace staticProperty
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1();
            c1.????
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Class1.name` would cause a `StackOverflowException` (if you could access it).

Comment: Private property can be set or get within the class

Comment: Just do `public string Name { get; set; }` which will create a property with a public getter and setter and an implicit private backing field.

Comment: property keyword does no kill encapsulation

Comment: ok i understand

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the same layout as Java with

```
class Class1
{
    private string _name;

    public string getName(){
        return _name;
    }

    //methods to set the private variable anywhere in here.
}
```

Or more concise

```
class Class1
{
   public string Name{ get; private set; }
}
```

The getter will be public in both cases, but setting will be private.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to call private property in a class.

I write the following code example, and you could have a look.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student stu = new Student();
            PropertyInfo property = stu.GetType().GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            property.SetValue(stu,"test1");   //set value
            string value = property.GetValue(stu).ToString();//get value
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
    public class Student
    {
        private string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
private string name;

public string _name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}
```

So I understand property is like getter setter and it should be public.

Question is that if i make public property direct without variable than it should be public and treated as public class or outer class